# Passing more than one int between processes via pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I'm new to C. My question is more related to syntax. I know how to use pipe to send integer over the pipe.

writing to the pipe

```
int n = 50; 
write(fd[1], &n, sizeof(n));
```

reading from the pipe

```
int n;
read(fd[0], &n, sizeof(n));
```

But I want to know how do i modify the pipe to send 2 integers? I tried the code below but it didn't work.

writing to the pipe

```
int n1 = 50, n2 = 30; 
write(fd[1], &n1 &n2, sizeof(n1)+sizeof(n2));
```

reading from the pipe

```
int n1, n2;
read(fd[0], &n1 &n2, sizeof(n1)+sizeof(n2));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `char n[2] = {50,30}; write(fd[1], n, sizeof(n));` The signature of `write` function does not magically change to accept 2 buffer addresses. You must provide 1 buffer holding all the data. Same for `read`

Comment: You also have to call `write` in a loop because it's not guaranteed to write the entire requested amount. (Same for `read`)

Comment: You could use `writev` and `readv` but then you would also need arrays of `struct iovec`. In this case, it is easier to use `write` and `read` on arrays of `int`.

Comment: Your biggest issue is that "&n1 &n2" doesn't parse the way you think it does.

The first "&" takes the address of n1.  The second one tries to do a bitwise AND with n2.

Which doesn't even compile under gcc, giving an error that you cannot do a bitwise and between an int pointer (int *) and an int.